# PHP handling a MySQL INSERT INTO command

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've had an issue that's been bugging me for a while now. I don't know if I'm being blind or stupid but I have a MySQL query embedded in a php page. When it executes, nothing happens! This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO objective (IdUser, CreationYear, Description) 
VALUES ('$idFor','$date','$textAreaObjective1a')
```

I decided to echo the query out and it produces the full line of text that I need. When I copy and paste the line straight into MySQL it executes the query adds the row to the database.

```
INSERT INTO objective (IdUser, CreationYear, Description) 
VALUES ('2', '20130314', 'hello 1')
```

**EDIT** Here is the PHP code used for the insert -

```
$objectiveCreation = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO objective (IdUser, CreationYear, Description) 
    VALUES ('$idFor','$date','$textAreaObjective1a')");
```

So the issue is, why can't php handle the command? I've tried putting all values in quotations and removing all quotations. Echoing out the command then copy and pasting it manually resolves it and adds the data so the query seems to be fine. I added the mysql_error() command just after the query and it return the following error:

```
Unknown column 'CreationYear' in 'field list'
```

The column is in the database. Here is the structure:

```
    IdObjective         int(10)
    IdUser              int(10)
    PercenOfComp        float
    CreationYear        date            
    Description         text
    Status              varchar(45)
```

Comment: Could it be that this is not the `objective` table?

Comment: Can it be `objective` table from another database?

Comment: -1 for "why can't php handle the command"

Comment: Please update your question with the full create statement for the table - `SHOW CREATE TABLE objective` and all the relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
INSERT INTO `objective` (`IdUser`, `CreationYear`, `Description`) VALUES ('2', '20130314', 'hello 1')
```

You can also open phpmyadmin and use the insert function (in horizontal menu bar when vieuwing a table) and fill in the fields press go and copy the query as shown.

Comment: Throws back a different error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''objective' (IdUser, CreationYear, Description)' at line 1

Comment: Did you use backticks or single quotes? That does not look like a suitable error for running that query. Please update your question with the PHP code you are using to execute this query.

Comment: $objectiveCreation = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `objective` (`IdUser`, `CreationYear`, `Description`)
VALUES ('$idFor','$date','$textAreaObjective1a')");

Still comes back with the initial error now.

Comment: copy my line please, you need to use brackets instead of quotes, you can also open phpmyadmin use the insert function and copy the query when its done

Comment: None of the strings are reserved words or contain special characters so the use of backticks is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$dateToBeInserted=date("Y-m-d", $date);`

Since you defined `date` as the type, MYSQL expects it to be like this : `2013-03-14`

Comment: The DATE datatype does not take time so the time parts of your $dateToBeInserted will be truncated.

Comment: When inserting into a DATE field it will allow any of the following formats - `VALUES (20120311), ('20120312'), ('2012-03-13')`

Answer (score 0):

I have run your query, that works perfect for me. You can try this one too -

```
INSERT INTO `objective` ( `IdUser` , `CreationYear` , `Description` ) VALUES ( 2, '20130314', 'hello 1' ) ;
```

It will show something like below in phpMyAdmin using xampp-

[image]

As the "CreationYear" field is of type date so it will automatically convert your data into MySQL default date format before inserting in the table. But still you can try the following -

INSERT INTO `objective` ( `IdUser` , `CreationYear` , `Description`  ) VALUES (2, '2013-03-14', 'hello 1');

You can also try the following to auto-format date inside MySQL query -

```
INSERT INTO `objective` ( `IdUser` , `CreationYear` , `Description` ) VALUES ('2', DATE( 20130314 ) , 'hello 1');
```